# How to hide displaying terminal command output

Tags: bash, shell, sh

When I run this command,

```
sudo htpasswd -b /home/reynolds/.htpasswd admin admin
```

I am getting output `Updating password for user admin` in terminal but I dont want to display that output. So I searched some in google and try with the following commands.

```
sudo htpasswd -b /home/reynolds/.htpasswd admin admin 2>&1
sudo htpasswd -b /home/reynolds/.htpasswd admin admin > /dev/null
```

But still I am getting that output in terminal.Please help to avoid displaying such output while running this command. Please advice me as I am a very beginner in shell scripting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
 > /dev/null
```

and normal output is suppressed but errors are still shown

follow the command with

```
 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and everything, including errors is supressed

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following;

```
sudo htpasswd -b /home/reynolds/.htpasswd admin admin > /dev/null 2>&1
```

should hide everything!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is that `sudo` only applies to the very first command in the argument list.

The way to get around this is to encapsulate your command like so, using bash as an example:

```
sudo bash -c "htpasswd -b /home/reynolds/.htpasswd admin admin 2>&1"
```

Just remember that this creates a new bash shell, so any relative paths will not work and make sure that any environment variables you rely on, etc. are all available as well.