# Rust: Is there a way to display stdout until first input, then hide after that?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments

I don't know if this is possible, but here's a scenerio..

```sh
# Call `mysql` from inside a running container named "db"

cargo run my-command "docker exec -it db mysql -u user -p my-database"
```

This will result in the mysql command pausing execution at a password prompt. However, upon typing the password and pressing enter, the Rust program should inject some other arguments (not shown) into the quoted command and the final output will be a bunch of text.

```rust
let args = [
   "docker", "exec", "-it", "db", "mysql", "-u", "user", "-p"
];

// `sudo` only used for testing. It's needed for docker,
// but `sudo cargo run ...` doesn't work
let cmd = process::Command::new("sudo")
    .args(&args)
    .spawn() // stdout will be inherited
    .expect("external cmd failed.")
    .wait_with_output()?;
```

But, the output will be processed in `my-command` and shouldn't be displayed to the user.

Is there a way to pause the child command on the first input, and switch the stdout to be piped?

I tried to check for input before waiting on the child to finish

```
// ... snip

let mut cmd = process::Command::new("sudo")
        .args(&args)
        .spawn()
        .expect("external cmd failed.");

let mut s = String::new();
// Trying to inspect the stdout for the if check below,
// but this will panic
let mut out = cmd.stdout.take().unwrap();
out.read_to_string(&mut s);

if s.contains("password") {
    // From now on, don't display child's stdout
}

let output = cmd.wait_with_output()?;

let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);

// do something with the result
```

But that just seems to pause *all* execution until pressing enter.

**Update**

Perhaps the child's stdin can remain inherited, but the child's stdout can be initialized with `.stdout(process::stdio::piped())` and the parent can catch the output somehow and display it conditionally?

Comment: What if you used `sudo sh -c 'docker exec -it db mysql -u user -p my-database > /dev/null'` instead. That should run `sudo` normally, but when `sh` gets run it would redirect its output to `/dev/null`. I had to search a bit to find the right command to do what you wanted, but I imagine Linux already has the built-in utilities to cover your use case.

Comment: @Locke I just tried your suggestion. It doesn't prompt for the password, it just does nothing until pressing enter to end it.

Comment: What about `sudo bash -c 'docker ... > /dev/null'`? I'm citing other answers that look roughly correct. You will likely have better luck if you ask https://unix.stackexchange.com/ about the proper approach and syntax. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40923293/5987669

Comment: After reading the linked thread, I think there's a misunderstanding.. I'm not trying to discard the child process's output, I'm trying to wait for it to ask for input, so the user can see mysql's password prompt, but afterwards change the child process's stdout to "piped" instead of "inherit" so the rust program takes control of the child process's output *after* the prompt and *before* further output to then save it into a variable.